# android- do we need sdk build tools for each SDK platform?

Tags: android, sdk

the android SDK folder is taking up a lot of my drive space and I was wondering that [do we an need individual version of build tools for every sdk platform?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8kH0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no we don't need and individual Version for every sdk Plattform

Comment: appreciate the quick reply....so if i remove all other previous versions of the build tools i'm hoping that it wont affect the application compatibility of the apps I make. Is this correct?

Comment: it will not ! you just Need to configure the build.gradle of the apps with the most recent build Tools, which is the only one you Need to have installed